# Experimenting with pointers of arrays in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have an array `a` whose values I wish to modify through another function. This is the code that I have:

```
#include "stdlib.h" 
#include "stdio.h"

void myfunc(int* );

int main() {

    int *a, i;

    a = (int*) calloc(10,sizeof(int));
    myfunc(&a);

    for (i=0; i<10; i++) printf("%d\n", a[i]);

    return 0;
}

void myfunc(int* a) {

    int i;

    for (i=0; i<10; i++) *a[i] = i;
}
```

Obviously something is wrong with my syntax and I Was wondering if someone could lend me a hand :)

Thanks!

Comment: In case anyone's wondering, I'm getting errors of `cannot convert int** to int*`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the main function, you've got a pointer to an integer, `a`. Then you pass the address of this pointer to `myfunc`, but `myfunc` is expecting a pointer to an int, not a pointer to a pointer to an int. You need to change your call to `myfunc` to this:

```
myfunc(a);
```

But, you've also got a problem inside `myfunc`. You don't need to dereference `a[i]` since that indexes into an array `a`. These are (effectively) the same thing:

```
a[i]
```

and

```
*(a+i)
```

(This isn't 100%, I think, because in C pointers and arrays are not completely the same thing, so some expert C programmer can correct me)

You're probably just get a bit confused by the collection of syntax around pointers and arrays:

```
&a
*a
a[i]
*(a+i)
```

The first one is the address of `a`, the second dereferences `a` as a pointer, the third is an index into an array and the fourth is dereferencing `a` as a pointer with an offset.

You would only want to do this `*(a[i])` if you had an array of pointers, not a pointer to an int.

Answer (score 3):

you already declare "a" as a pointer when you say its type is "int*". Therefore, when you try and call your function "myfunc" you don't need to take the address of "a". This will make it a pointer to pointer or "int**". If you want to change the location of where a pointer is pointing, you might use that, but in your case where you just want to change the data it is pointing at, your myfunc is declared fine and you should just change the call of your function from:

```
myfunc(&a);
```

to

```
myfunc(a);
```

Also inside your function the "a" variable is already a pointer so to access an element in the array it is pointing to, you don't need to dereference it first. You should just use a[i] instead of *a[i].

Comment: I get `invalid argument of 'unary *'`

Comment: @Amit Because operator `*` has a lower priority then `[]`. Therefore you are dereferencing something that is not a pointer.

Comment: Ya thanks for pointing that out, I didn't see that problem too. I will update the original answer to be more clear.

Comment: @LetMeBe: I see. I'm really new to C and this will probably sound very stupid, but what is "dereferencing" ?

Comment: "Dereferencing" is following a pointer through to what it points to. If you have a pointer to an int, the value of the pointer is an address, and dereferencing looks up that address and returns what's inside it (or allows you to change the contents in the case of assignment).

Comment: @Amit Accessing a memory location through an address stored in a pointer variable. You should read up a bit of theory.

Comment: Dereferencing means accessing the value that is pointed to by a pointer. The "\*" in front of the variable is a "dereference" operator. So to access the value pointed to by int* a, you can write it as "int b = 3 + \*a;"

Comment: And it's not stupid! It takes some practice to come naturally, and the syntax in C is not really immediately obvious.

Answer (score 1):

It is enought to call `myfunc(a)` instead of `myfunc(&a)`, then inside the function you use a[i] directly. By declaring `myfunc(&a)` you are passing an int ** that allow you to *allocate* the array from *inside the *function* and returning to the caller to use it.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `*a[i] = i;` you can just put `a[i] = i;` (and modify your function call as Felice pointed out).

Comment: there we, perfect, The combination of your comment and Felice worked

Answer (score 0):

Since `a` is `int*` , `&a` will be `int**`. So you should change your function signature to `void myfunc(int** a);`

Comment: Okay, changed it to `int**`, compiled fine, thanks, but when ran it, i got a Bus Error

Comment: @Amit You are getting the bus error because operator `*` has lower priority then `[]`.

Comment: just to modify the array content you don't need at all to pass an int**, see my reply,