# Returning arrays with C, different approaches

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I've previously asked this question: [Experimenting with pointers of arrays in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5613297/experimenting-with-pointers-of-arrays-in-c) regarding passing pointers to functions and modifying existing arrays within functions as a way to "return" an array to `main()`. I'm left with a question though, what's the difference between these two code blocks?

```
// #includes

int ***myfunc(int*** );

int main() 
{
    int a***;
    //allocate memory for array 'a'
    a = myfunc(a);

    // display all contents of array 'a'

    return 0;
}
```

OR

```
// #includes

void myfunc(int*** );

int main() 
{
    int a***;
    //allocate memory for array 'a'
    myfunc(a);

    // display all contents of array 'a'

    return 0;
}
```

Both functions will modify the array and when `displaying all contents of a`, the contents will be the same.

I hope this isn't confusing, I guess I could elaborate more if needed.

**a significant EDITTTTTTTTT**

Below are two working examples (as far as I know):

```
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "stdio.h"


void myfunc(int** );

int main() {

  int **a,i, j;

  a = (int**) calloc(10,sizeof(int*));
  for (i=0; i<10; i++)
    a[i] = (int*) calloc(10, sizeof(int));

  myfunc(a);

  for (i=0; i<10; i++) {
    for (j=0; j<10; j++)
      printf("%d ",a[i][j]);
    printf("\n");
  }

  return 0;
}


void myfunc(int** a) {

  int i, j;
  for (i=0; i<10; i++)
    for (j=0; j<10; j++)
      a[i][j] = i*j;

}
```

AND...

```
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "stdio.h"

// returning arrays through functions

int **myfunc(int **b);

int main() {

  int **a,i,j;

  a = (int**) calloc(10,sizeof(int*));
  for (i=0; i<10; i++)
    a[i] = (int*) calloc(10, sizeof(int));

  a = myfunc(a);

  for (i=0; i<10; i++) {
    for (j=0; j<10; j++)
      printf("%d ",a[i][j]);
    printf("\n");
  }

  return 0;
}


int **myfunc(int **b) {

  int i, j;
  for (i=0; i<10; i++)
    for (j=0; j<10; j++)
      b[i][j] = i*j;

  return b;
}
```

Comment: What are so many "***" doing there?

Comment: I think the difference is that in the first version, you could save at least one `*`. If you think you need pointers to pointers to pointers, you may want to rethink the problem.

Comment: 3d array. we can make it * for all intensive purposes

Comment: Perhaps the function which returns the pointers assumes that it may have to reallocate, thus returning a different pointer than the argument.

Comment: @Amit: Do you mean "intents and purposes"?

Comment: @Amit: I think you also meant `int ***a`, not `int a***`, yes?

Comment: @Tomalak: yes, to `***a`, and I guess thanks for correcting my grammar...

Comment: @Amit: Then please correct the code in your question. (And, as for your phrasing, grammar has nothing to do with it...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second function cannot modify the pointer (`int***`) that you pass into it, but when you do an allocation you will get a new memory address. This new address will be assigned to the local copy of the pointer *inside* `myfunc`, but it'll never reach `main`.

The consequence of this is that you will:

- Use an invalid pointer inside `main`
- Leak the memory allocated inside `myfunc`.

You can mitigate this by taking a pointer to your pointer (whew!):

```
// #includes

void myfunc(int****);

int main() 
{
    int ***a; // <-- note: you had a typo here, originally!

    //allocate memory for array 'a'
    myfunc(&a); // <-- pass pointer by pointer

    // display all contents of array 'a'

    return 0;
}
```

and ensure that `myfunc` is intelligent about it.

The above code can be made a little clearer with `typedef`:

```
// #includes
typedef int*** Ptr;

void myfunc(Ptr*);

int main() 
{
    Ptr a;

    //allocate memory for array 'a'
    myfunc(&a); // <-- pass pointer by pointer

    // display all contents of array 'a'

    return 0;
}
```

Still, your first approach is far cleaner and avoids any need for this nonsense. It just returns the new value for the pointer that you can then assign and use as you please.

---

**Edit** *(response to significant question edit)*

I had understood that the memory allocation was done in `myfunc`; I see now that that is not the case.

Therefore you could use any of the two methods you listed (or the third that I describe above); and, frankly, I don't see why you'd bother with the first as you won't be modifying the pointer inside `myfunc`.

Comment: I see. However, I've used the second method and both work. Are you saying that sometimes memory leakage can occur and the first method is safer?

Comment: @Amit: I don't see how the second could work. Unless I'm missing something, you're invoking undefined behaviour and using memory that doesn't actually belong to you. If it appears to "work", then that's just bad luck; it could crash or cause other symptoms of memory corruption at any time.

Comment: @Amit: You have misunderstood. I can show you broken, invalid code that _appears_ to be a "working example" for decades until it suddenly breaks down because in actual fact you've been using invalid memory the entire time. Don't fall into the trap of thinking that _any_ invalid memory access immediately causes a nice, predictable `Segmentation Fault`: this is **not** the case.

Comment: @Tomalak: I see, so in the future, use the first method which actually returns the value for the pointer?

Comment: @Amit: In my opinion, yes. Or you could use the third approach that I demonstrated.

Comment: @Amit: See my edit please. It answers your own edits. (And now you've magically gone from `int**` to `int***`? What?!)

Comment: I've gone from `int***` to `int**` because those two examples are the ones I've written previously. Hope that change doesn't end the world...In my actual work, I use `int***`, which is why I originally started with that.

Comment: @Amit: OK. I think the world will survive, cheeky.

Answer (score 0):

You want to modify the value of `a`, so you must pass a pointer to it, not the value itself:

```
myfunc(&a); // as opposed to myfunc(a);
```

If you want to return a pointer to the thing you allocate *as well as* modify the input parameter, then you'd use one less level of indirection in the return type:

```
int **myfunc(int ***a) { ... }
```

so the call in main would look something like

```
int **a, **b;

b = myfunc(&a);
```

Comment: His base pointer type is `int***`. If he wants to pass the pointer by pointer, then that becomes `int****`.

Comment: +1 @Tomalak it was only a matter of time before someone managed to work `int****` into this question!

Comment: @David: Then I hope you enjoyed my answer. :)